# place TitlePageIndicator of the ViewPagerIndicator library next to another view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using the `ViewPagerIndicator` library by Jack Wharton and want to place the `TitlePageIndicator` next to some other view, which doesn't work. For some reason, the titles of the views are misplaced and don't appear above the thick indicator line.

[image: misplaced text]

When I scroll to the right, i.e., to the next page of the `ViewPager`, `INFOS` doesn't disappear but stays at the same position:

[image: scrolling]

How can I avoid this behaviour? My `layout.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/head"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/names"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_line_whisky">

            <TextView .../>

            <TextView .../>

        </LinearLayout>


        <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/titles"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well, your redacted layout will make it difficult for anyone to help you. Try using Hierarchy View to see what is going on.

Comment: I only removed background settings, colors etc. Everything layout related is included in the code. I just wanted to make it more readable. The hierarchy looks fine, the view is sized exactly the way I want to. (Note, that the red line below the left view does not belong to the `TitlePagerIndicator`). Also note, that the `TitlePageIndicator` is a custom view that does not contain any other view hierarchy, just an `onDraw` method.

Comment: "Everything layout related is included in the code" -- the screenshots show 1-2 `TextView` widgets ("ABERFELDY 12Y", etc.).

Comment: Right, I'm sorry. Those are the first `...`. I'll edit  the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the `TitlePagerIndicator` with another View apparently solves the issue.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```